# How to combine 2 columns of the same matrix and arrange the values in alternating rows?

Tags: r, matrix, transform

Probably, it will be an easy one, just can't get my head around it today. 
How can I combine 2 columns of the same matrix in such a way that element 1 from column 1 of the original matrix will be followed by element 1 from column 2 and so on? E.g. the original matrix may look like the one below:

```
set.seed(200)
m <- matrix(sample(1:100, 10, replace=FALSE), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=NULL)
m

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   54   58
[2,]   99   68
[3,]   65   80
[4,]   67    9
[5,]   49   22
```

What I would like to achieve should look like this:

```
      [,1]
 [1,]   54
 [2,]   58
 [3,]   99
 [4,]   68
 [5,]   65
 [6,]   80
 [7,]   67
 [8,]    9
 [9,]   49
[10,]   22
```

How do I then transform the original matrix to achieve the arrangement shown in the second matrix? Of course it's only an example, not a real data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `c` or `as.vector` on the transpose (`t`) of your matrix, like this:

```
c(t(m))
#  [1] 54 58 99 68 65 80 67  9 49 22
```

Wrap it again in `matrix` if you want a single column matrix like you show (or, as noted in the comments, you can skip the `c` or `as.vector` at this stage since you're not supplying any dimensions to the matrix you are creating).

```
matrix(c(t(m)))
#       [,1]
#  [1,]   54
#  [2,]   58
#  [3,]   99
#  [4,]   68
#  [5,]   65
#  [6,]   80
#  [7,]   67
#  [8,]    9
#  [9,]   49
# [10,]   22
```

Comment: Arghhh, you beat me to it again. +1

Comment: You don't even need the `c` function if you make a matrix out of it: `matrix(t(m))`

Comment: @Mike.Gahan thanks, but please dont assume I know all the rules after posting only 2 questions here so far.